# Prints the SQL for all migration django

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have django application, where I wanted to export all migration from my project , auth and admin to sql query. I am able to do

`python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0001`

However, I want to export all migration at same time rather than explicitly righting loops. Is there any package or tool that i can use for this.

Comment: Which database are you using? You could just dump the table definitions from your database?

Comment: I am doing that. but I wanted to see if I can do without sql using django

Answer (score 6):

you can use [squashmigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) command

```
python manage.py squashmigrations <appname> <squashfrom> <squashto>
```

and press y

Delete all the before migration files

then run the following command

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate <appname> <squash_generated_migartion_file>
```

if you wanted to see the sql for auth migrations

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate auth 0001_initial
```

Answer (score -1):

First make sure you are on directory with manage.py file i.e. project directory then, you can do

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and then run
`python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py sqlmigrate`

Comment: I am trying to Prints the SQL for all migration django. I can use  python manage.py sqlmigrate one by one. However, I am trying to see if there is too that does for all migration at same time.